# How to open and display pdf using qt in raspberry pi

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pdf, raspberry-pi

I have raspberry pi3. I want to open and display pdf file using qt in raspberry pi. So i had written the code, but while running that, it is giving me error like: no module named QtPoppler even i had install poppler using command: `sudo apt-get install python-poppler`. Any one know how to solve this error? Please Reply.

Comment: If you get this error message, then it is unable to import the module. Full stop. Can you try to import the module only? Maybe in a command prompt (type `python`, then `import QtPoppler`)? Do you get an error message when running `apt-get ...`?

Comment: Thanks @nostradamus...but i tried using command prompt also like (type python, then import QtPoppler) but in both case it is showing error like no module named QtPoppler....when i running using apt-get also showing same error. Can u plz tell tell me how to solve this or how to import it?

Comment: Hard to diagnose like that. Which exact error do you get when you try to install it with `sudo apt-get`? What's your OS and your Python version? Do these work with QtPoppler?

Comment: I m getting error like: ImportError:no module named QtPoppler. my os is raspbian jessie and my python version is 2.7.9.

Comment: That can hardly be the error when you do `apt-get`, right? If anything, it could be "no module named QtPoppler found" or something along these lines... Furthermore, it seems like there are different versions and names around... [One](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-poppler-qt4/) is `import popplerqt4`, the [other](http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/rendering-pdf-files-pyqt4-pypoppler-qt4/) is `import QtPoppler`.

Comment: ok i add import popplerqt4 in place of import QtPoppler,so that eroor disabled but now showing no module named pictureflow...do u have any idea how to import it or how to solve it?

Comment: It's getting lenghty here... It's always the same, isn't it? How did you install the module? Any error messages during installation? Searched for the errors? If downloaded manually, have you seen [this](http://arielvb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/development/pictureflow.html)? Everyone here is very bad at soothsaying, so you have to provide the necessary bit of information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135570/discussion-between-snehal-desai-and-nostradamus).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume from your imports that you are using Qt4.

Install the correct version of Poppler for Qt4 :

```
apt-get install python-poppler-qt4
```

Then import the python binding of Poppler in the proper way:

```
import popplerqt4
```

Source: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-poppler-qt4/

Comment: Thanks @gortsu...it is worked for me but now i m running it is showing another error like: no module named pictureflow. I follow this link to solve that: http://arielvb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/development/pictureflow.html but i can't find path /Applications/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib sugested in that link...do u have any idea how to install pictureflow?...plz suggest steps if u have.